# formula for exel to calculate how many days from speefic date untill today?

Tags: microsoft-excel

is there is any formula for exel to calculate how many days from specific date until today ?

for example if i wrote in column A 31 july

so from 31 july until today it's 4 days

i don't want to calculate manually as i have huge dates

can u help me with this please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**=today()-a1**

will return decimals, for example 1.5 for 1 day and 12 hours.

**=int(today()-a1)**

will return just the whole number

Comment: thanks alot
i need: =int(today()-a1)
can i change the formula today to 31 july 2010 ?
i tried but i got error

Comment: The format must be acceptable to Excel. For details see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214094

Comment: still i can't use the format that i want exactly, ( replace today date with 31 july 2010

but thanks for ur help. it's realy save my time now 
thanks alot